# Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> ())?'

Tags: swift

I've migrated my iOS Swift 3 application to Swift 4.
I got:

> Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> ())?'

error trying to call this method:

```
self.aPIManager.registerDeviceId(deviceTokenStr,onSuccess:{
            getRegister in
},
    onError: { message in
        AppUtility.hideLoading(self.window!)
})
```

Here is declaration of `aPIManager.registerDeviceId`:

```
open  func registerDeviceId(_ deviceId: String, onSuccess successBlock: (() -> ())!, onError errorBlock: ((String?) -> Void)!) {
    ...
}
```

Here are the same functions in Swift 3 before moving to Swift 4:

```
open  func registerDeviceId(_ deviceId: String, onSuccess successBlock: 

(() -> Void)!, onError errorBlock: ((String?) -> Void)!) {
   ...        
}
```

And here is the call:

```
self.aPIManager.registerDeviceId(deviceTokenStr,onSuccess:{
        getRegister in
},
    onError: { message in
        AppUtility.hideLoading(self.window!)
})
```

I'm new to swift. I would be grateful if you provide me some information about this type of function declaration (function without name in it declaration).

Comment: You success closure  has no argument but you have  used it while calling ===> onSuccess:{
            **getRegister** in .... }   remove  `getRegister in`

Comment: I'm wondering why it does not lead to error in Swift 3

Comment: Could you please show old code ? then I might help you

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I did update the question.

Comment: “I'm wondering why it does not lead to error in Swift 3” The problem is that in Swift 4 the meaning of `!` has changed.

Comment: @matt Can you explain more please? or provide the right syntax?

Comment: Simple. Do not use `!` in a parameter type. If you need a type to be an Optional, use `?`.

Comment: @matt Can you provide any reference for meaning of operator ! in swift 3 or swift4?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md is a good place to start.